# Delete the latest record of a day grouped by user id

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following fields

```
id (int),
userid (int),
date_time(datetime),
kw (float)
```

Now I have to make some cleaning-up. That means to delete all records and only keep the LAST record of a day for every user.

I'm really stuck in this, so any help will be appreciated...

Thx

Comment: FWIW, I'd create a new table with only the desired info. Then just drop the old table and rename/re-index the new table as required.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use the `join` syntax in `delete`.  So, this should work:

```
delete t1
    from table t1 join
         (select date(date_time) as thedate, max(date_time) as max_date_time
          from table t
          group by date(date_time)
         ) tmax
         on date(t1.date_time) = tmax.thedate and
            t1.date_time < tmax.max_date_time;
```